# How to match some digits but exclude some constant(also digits) from Regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

In C#, I would like to replace all sensitive digits and replace/mask with **** but there are some other digits I would not like to replace such as phone number which is a constant.

This is what I am doing now

```
String original = "this is your sensitive digit 12345 , if you have any question please call CONSTANTPHONENUMBER";
String pattern = @"[0-9]{4,}";
String result =  Regex.Replace(original, pattern, "****");
```

the result is

this is your sensitive digit **** , if you have any question please call ****

My question is how can I exclude that CONSTANTPHONENUMBER so that it wont be replaced.

The desired result

**"this is your sensitive digit **** , if you have any question please call CONSTANTPHONENUMBER"**

Comment: Is there any specific length of sensitive digits?

Comment: Yes there is, lets say it is 4

Comment: CONSTANTPHONENUMBER which I am trying to exclude from masking is a constant

Comment: I'd suggest you keep the constant as separate string if you don't want it to be mutated. `String result =  Regex.Replace(original, pattern, "****") + "if you have any question please call 999999999";`. Is there any reason you haven't tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest one I could think of is to use negative lookahead surrounded by `\b` (word boundary). Also with multiple exclusions:

```
var str = "Digit 1 is 12345, please call 111222 or 334455";
var pat = @"\b(?!111222|334455)\b\d{4,}";
System.Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(str, pat, "****"));
// Digit 1 is ****, please call 111222 or 334455
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below,

```
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d{4,}\d");
    string replacedstar = rgx.Replace( input, "*****", 1 );
```

I used [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-8.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-int32)) method from `Regex` class. Last `int` parameter will update digit only once.

[.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HG79Gr)

---

As per the latest requirement, I couldn't think of Regex. Here is some hacky way.

```
    var split = input.Split("please call"); //Split into two strings
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(split.Length == 2)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d{4,}\d");
        string replacedstar = rgx.Replace( split[0], "*****"); //Mask all the sensitive pins    
        return replacedstar + "please call" + string.Join("", split.Skip(1).ToList()); //Merge it to original
    }
    return input; //Otherwise return as it is.
```

Comment: this could have worked if I had only one sensitive number in the string, but there may be more than one sensitive number in the given string. In addition, modification of the string is not under my control.

Comment: No, this will work for your case. Consider you have 5 numbers in your string. This will update only the **first occurrence of the 4-digit number** in your string.

Comment: @davecole, I added fiddle to try my solution. It is working fine. Take a look and play around it. If it does not work with your requirement let me know

Comment: Thanks @Prasad, but in my case the occurrence of sensitive digit/number is unknown, it could be once or more than once, So I do not know the last int params ahead of time. I am looking for the regex pattern just to match all sensitive digits but exclude the phonenumber(known and constant) so it will not be masked or replaced

Comment: What is the **specific criteria** of finding sensitive digits?

Comment: for e.g "this is your sensitive digit 12345 , the access code is 4567 if you have any question please call +91999999999999 and my home number is +123 3241 432423" will not work, which will only cover the first occurrence.

Comment: could be any number with >=4 digits but occurrence is arbitrary, but I know the exact digit(phonenumber) which should not be masked or matched

Comment: Does that mean, you would like to mask all the numbers except phone number in given string?

Comment: @davecole, I updated my answer. I would say this is not the best solution, but you can use it. It will work

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Regex.Escape**  followed by **Replace**. Below is the code

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("sensitiveNumber"));
var newText = regex.Replace("Your String Here...", "****", 1);
```

Here we are using **overload of Regex.Replace**. And specifying **1** which means **no of times to replace**. so it will replace only one time occurrence of string **mentioned in Escape**.

**For Example**

1. **Scenario - 1**

   var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("o"));

   var newText = regex.Replace("Hello World", "****", 1);

   **Output**  : Hell**** World
2. **Scenario - 2**

   var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("o"));

   var newText = regex.Replace("Hello World", "****", 2);

   **Output**  : Hell**** W****rld

Comment: what you are achieving is exactly what I am getting now, but I also want to exclude some non-sensitive digits such as phonenumber as in my example

Comment: If phone no is known then simply use Replace Function in C#
regex.Replace("Your String Here...", "****", 1).Replace("YourPhoneNo","");

Answer (score 0):

I would just replace all digits using the [MatchEvaluator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-8.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)):

```
var newText = Regex.Replace(original, @"[+]?\d+", Evaluator);


string Evaluator(Match match) =>
    match.Value == "CONSTANTPHONENUMBER" ? "CONSTANTPHONENUMBER" : "****";
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HwVLq9)

The `MatchEvaluator` is a function and you can check for your phone number.

Comment: thanks @Sebastian, your solution also works but i need to add something quickly to evaluator and I have very limited knowledge of Evaluator. thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @davecole The `MatchEvaluator` is only a delegate - a normal method, that receives the `Match` and returns the string that replaces the match. You can do whatever you want writing C# code.